# How to pass all objects to Pageable

Tags: java, jpa, repository

I have a method where I pass only 6 objects from database :

```
StudentDTO students = StudentDTO.builder()
            .fieldName("studentCity")
            .postDTOS(postRepository.findStudentByCity(
                    PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), 6))
                    .map(postMapper::toPostDTO).toSet()).build();
```

How can I rewrite it in order to pass all values, not 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Pageable.unpaged();` to fetch all the records:

```
StudentDTO students = StudentDTO.builder()
            .fieldName("studentCity")
            .postDTOS(postRepository.findStudentByCity(
                    Pageable.unpaged())
                    .map(postMapper::toPostDTO).toSet()).build()
```

Comment: Can I do the same with existing instance pageable that passes to this method ?